# hash as reference throwing warnings of deprecation

Tags: perl, hash

I am having a perl subroutine in my perl script

```
sub constructSummaryString {
    my ( $SummaryHash, $SeverityHash, $Component ) = @_;
    foreach my $Key ( keys %$SummaryHash ) {
        print %$SeverityHash->{$Key};         # <---  Warning at line:163
    }
}
```

The input to the Subroutine are hash references.

When i try to run it I get a warning:

```
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at xxxoo.pl line 163.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning means what it says it means: You are using a hash as a reference, and that is deprecated. Look at the statement:

```
%$SeverityHash->{$Key}
```

Here, `%$SeverityHash` is your hash ref being dereferenced into a hash. This: `->{$Key}` is you using that as a reference.

What you need to do is use the reference as a reference, and not try and dereference it.

```
$SeverityHash->{$Key}
```

Answer (score 4):

The left hand side of `->` must be a reference, so it must be a scalar. As such,

```
%$SeverityHash->{...}
```

should evaluate `%$SeverityHash` in scalar context.

```
>perl -E"my $SeverityHash = { a=>1, b=>2, c=>3 }; say scalar(%$SeverityHash)"
3/8
```

That means

```
%$SeverityHash->{...}
```

should be equivalent to

```
"3/8"->{...}   # Access the element of the hash named '3/8'.
```

Fortunately for you, there's a bug in Perl which causes the `%` to be ignored, so

```
%$SeverityHash->{...}
```

is actually equivalent to

```
$SeverityHash->{...}
```

but a deprecation warning tells you that you are relying on this bug.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
print %$SeverityHash->{$Key}
```

with

```
print $SeverityHash->{$Key}
```